# Microsoft Analysis Services Translations

Tags: c#, .net, olap

I have the following scenario:

From .NET (v3.5, c#) I connect to an OLAP Cube using the Microsoft.AnalysisServices namespace and objects in order to manage dinamycally the translations of dimensions, measures, attributes,etc.

A sample code updating an attribute caption translation looks like this:

```
foreach (DimensionAttribute dimAttribute in dimension.Attributes)
{
  dimAttribute.Translations.Add(1043, "Some caption") //language code
}
```

However, the above code throws an "InvalidOperationException" -- "The item type Translation is not valid"

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrelevant ... the code throwing the exception was elsewhere